# Android toolbar background

Tags: android, imageview, toolbar

How can I add imageview on toolbar that it would be behind drawer and back arrow icons? that imageview should match toolbar height and wouldn't have any margins or padding on left side. I'm trying to achieve this for a while now and only solution I figured out to make custom Toolbar

Example:

[Toolbar example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6t0JJ.png)

Comment: Your duplicate doesn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
  <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:theme="@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ActionBarPopupThemeOverlay"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:background="@color/white">

              <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:src="@drawable/yourImage"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: But it would change toolbars whole background and I need that imageview to be for example 60dp wide

Comment: you mean app icon on Toolbar?

Comment: I added example how it should look

Comment: got it. so instead of  Toolbar go with a Relative Layout

Comment: check the edited answer

Answer (score 0):

create appbar_layout_xml in layouts add following code

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/my_img"
app:titleTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

and in your activity_xml include appbar_layout_xml layout 
in styles keep theme as NoActionBar